# I am getting a bad input for 'value: error in my Ada program

Tags: ada

This is Ada 2012, using the GNAT IDE.

I am trying to test my project and I am getting the following error

```
bad input for 'Value: "x         "
```

as the only output to the console. I think the issue comes from this function;

```vhdl
function get_next_id(lex: in out Lexical_Analyzer) return Id is
  tok: Token := get_lookahead_token(lex);
  tok_type: Token_Type := get_token_type(tok);
  theId: Id;
begin
  match(tok, ID_TOK);
  get_next_token(lex, tok);
  theId := create_id(Character'Value(String(get_lexeme(tok)))); -- Problem caused here?
  return theId;
end get_next_id;
```

I think this is causing my problem, it seems to be trying to convert the x and the white space that follows. How do I get it to only read the first element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is to use a substring of length 1.

```vhdl
declare
    S : constant String := Get_Lexeme (Tok);
begin
    theId := Create_Id (S (S'First));
end;
```

Note the use of 'First instead of assuming the first character is at index 1.